# PLY: Some derivations/grammar rules dont get fired leading to a Syntax error

Tags: python, compiler-construction, ply

I'm using PLY to parse through a C program with just the for construct. The issue that I have is that my program only seems to be accepting certain forms/cases of the for loop, giving a syntax error for others though I have written derivations for the ones the program seems to be failing on.

Code:

```
    import ply.lex as lex
    import ply.yacc as yacc
    tokens = ['HASH','HEADER_FILE','FLOW_OPEN','FLOW_CLOSE','SEMI_COLON',
    'TYPE','SMALL_OPEN','SMALL_CLOSE','IDENTIFIER','COLON',
    'ASSIGNMENT_OP','UNARY_OP','BINARY_OP','LITERAL','LOGICAL_OP']


    reserved = {'include' : 'INCLUDE', 'main': 'MAIN','int':'INT','void':'VOID','for':'FOR','switch':'SWITCH','case':'CASE','default':'DEFAULT','break':'BREAK'}

    tokens += reserved.values()

    t_HASH = r'\#'
    #t_INCLUDE = r'include'
    t_HEADER_FILE = r'<stdio.h>'
    #t_MAIN = r'main' 
    t_FLOW_OPEN = r'{'
    t_FLOW_CLOSE = r'}'
    t_SMALL_OPEN = r'\('
    t_SMALL_CLOSE = r'\)'
    t_SEMI_COLON = r';'
    t_ASSIGNMENT_OP = r'\='
    #t_IDENTIFIER = r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*'
    t_UNARY_OP = r'\++|\--'
    #t_BINARY_OP = r'[\+\-\*\/]'
    t_LITERAL = r'[0-9][0-9]*'
    t_LOGICAL_OP = r'\<|\>'
    t_COLON: r':'


    def t_check_reserved(t):
        r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*'
        if t.value in reserved:
            t.type = reserved[t.value]
        else:
            t.type = 'IDENTIFIER'
        return t

    def t_error(token):
        print(f'Illegal character: {token.value}')

    def t_whitespace(t):
        r'\s+'
        pass

    def t_COMMENT(t):
        r'(\/\/\/.*)|(\/\/\!.*)|(\/\/.*)|(\/\*[.\n]*.*\*\/)'
        pass

    def t_newline(t):
        r'\n+'
        t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

    lexer = lex.lex()
    #Building the parser

    def p_expression_start(p):
        'expression : header body'
        print('Derivation complete!')

    def p_header(p):
        'header : HASH INCLUDE HEADER_FILE'
        print('Deriving rule header')

    def p_body(p):
        'body : main rest'
        print('Deriving rule body')

    def p_main(p):
        'main : type MAIN SMALL_OPEN SMALL_CLOSE'
        print('Deriving rule main')


    def p_type(p):
        '''type : INT
                | VOID
         '''

    def p_rest(p):
        'rest : FLOW_OPEN st FLOW_CLOSE'
        print('Deriving rule rest')

    def p_st(p):
        '''
            st : IDENTIFIER SEMI_COLON st
                | type IDENTIFIER SEMI_COLON st
                | for
                | end
            '''
        print('Deriving rule st')


    def p_for(p):
        '''
        for : FOR SMALL_OPEN declarative SEMI_COLON num_expression SEMI_COLON update_expression SMALL_CLOSE FLOW_OPEN st FLOW_CLOSE
        '''
        print('Deriving rule for')

    def p_declarative(p):
        '''
        declarative : IDENTIFIER ASSIGNMENT_OP IDENTIFIER
                     | IDENTIFIER ASSIGNMENT_OP LITERAL

        '''

    def p_num_expression(p):
        ''' 
        num_expression : LITERAL
                        | IDENTIFIER
                        | conditional_expression  

        '''

    def p_conditional_expression(p):
        '''
        conditional_expression : IDENTIFIER LOGICAL_OP LITERAL
                                | IDENTIFIER LOGICAL_OP IDENTIFIER
                                | empty
        '''

    def p_update_expression(p):
        '''
        update_expression : IDENTIFIER UNARY_OP
                            | empty
        '''



    def p_end(p): #Empty production
        '''end :''' 
        print('Deriving rule end')

    def p_error(p):
        if p == None:
            token = "end of file"
        else:
            token = f"{p.type}({p.value}) on line {p.lineno}"

        print(f"Syntax error: Unexpected {token}")



    parser = yacc.yacc(method='LALR',debug=True)

    with open(r'forparsing.txt','r') as file:
        '''while True:
            try:
                line = next(file)
                print('Parsing')
                parser.parse(line)
            except:
                print('Finished')
                break
        '''
        content = file.read()
        parser.parse(content)
```

Some of the cases where this program is failing are:
1. when I give an identifier or a literal in the num_exp part of the 
for loop(i.e. in for(init_exp;num_exp;update_exp))
even though I have explicitly mentioned those cases in the grammar rule:

```
    def p_num_expression(p):
    ''' 
    num_expression : LITERAL
                    | IDENTIFIER
                    | conditional_expression  

    '''
```

Moreover,the C program only works when the conditional_expression part is of the form a>10 (IDENTIFER LOGICAL_OP IDENTIFIER) even though the grammar rule for this non-terminal is:

```
    def p_conditional_expression(p):
    '''
    conditional_expression : IDENTIFIER LOGICAL_OP LITERAL
                            | IDENTIFIER LOGICAL_OP IDENTIFIER
                            | empty
    '''
```

So, its only the first of the 3 possible derivations getting accepted. Using one of the other 2 forms is giving me a syntax error.

Edit: This is one of the inputs for which I get a syntax error:

```
# include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
for(a=15;1;a++)
{

}
}
```

This shouldnt be failing as one of my derivations for the non-terminal num_expression is num_expression -> LITERAL. However, if I replace the one with a conditional expression,something like a>10 then the derivation completes.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the grammar that I've written which is causing the parser to seemingly not consider some of the rules?

Comment: Please ensure that the code you include in the question can actually run. There are a number of syntax errors and several Ply errors as well. Also, please provide the exact literal input which fails, rather than just a rough description.

Comment: I've added an example of the input which fails. Could you please point out what ply errors Im making?

Comment: Missing definition of `empty`. Many unused tokens. Syntax error in the definition of t_COLON. Maybe some others I forgot.

Comment: The empty non-terminal is supposed to be an epsilon production i.e. it derives just epsilon. I didnt see an example in the docs of such a derivation but saw something like this being used elsewhere, so I did the same. The unused tokens all pertain to grammar rules for validating a switch statement which I'd begun to write in this program(stupidly,before checking whether all the variants of for loop are working or not). I'll fix the t_COLON mistake though, thanks.

Comment: if i can't copy and paste your code into a file and run it, I can't do much to help you. If your code won't compile or has a fatal Ply error, that means it is not the code you were using, so I cannot know if the problem you have in your real code is reproduced in the code in your question. For more info, see the help page on producing a [mcve].

Comment: Also, I had previously made the obvious fixes to your code by removing the word `empty` in two productions, and removing the definition of `t_COLON` (also from the token list), and then the code work as expected. So I cannot reproduce your issue with the code you supplied.

Comment: Oh crap, I'm sorry, I meant to write end and not empty. The end non-terminal is the epsilon production. The 'empty'  was a mistake-it should've been end. Here is the code as I'm currently running it:
https://pastebin.com/nqTDuNmL

When I try to run the program on the input I mentioned in my edit on the main post, I get:

Syntax error: Unexpected LITERAL(1) on line 1

Comment: That paste bin won't compile because you didn't fix the definition of `t_COLON`.

Comment: Also: I fixed the various errors in that pastebin as best I could, and then gave it your input verbatim. It parsed successfully. So I have no idea what you are actually doing which causes the problem.

Comment: OK; `t_COLON: r'\:'` is not a syntax error in Python 3.6+. But it doesn't assign `t_COLON`, either. Other errors: the use of ÇOLON instead of COLON at line 4 and an indentation error at line 113 (which leads to `conditional_expression` not being defined in the grammar).